# Inconsistency in 'useState()' working on React.JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner to React Hooks, and I met an issue that I hardly understand.

In code 1, If I understand it correctly the initial value of count passed in `useState()` is the same as the value passed in `setCount()` on button press and child components of the Counter component should not be re-rendered.

Code 1:

```
    function Counter() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
      console.log("in", count)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{count}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => {
            console.log("click")
            setCount(1) 
          }}>click</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

But in Code 2, if value passed to `setCount()` was different (and initial value of `count` is 1), a re-render of child components of  Counter component should take place once, and not more than once.
But for some reason it is re-rendering once more also(when count state is 2 and value setCount(2)) and not more than once, which shouldn't happen at all since count state is 2 and setCount(2) means state is unchanged.

Code 2:

```
    function Counter() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
      console.log("in", count)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{count}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => {
            console.log("click")
            setCount(2) 
          }}>click</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I am not sure if my understanding is correct about `useState()` on React Hooks. Or if anyone who could clarify how React Hooks useState works in detail would be much appreciate.

P.S
The react hooks version I am using is : **16.8.6**

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: It serves the same purpose as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount in React classes - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The react hooks version I am using is 16.8.6 as I edited on my question on above. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `useState` hook is such that when the state updater is called an extra time when the update is performed with the same value. This may be due to the fact that React uses Fiber architecture which has an expiration time which is useful in determining at what point of time React will commit the updates for the initial change it triggers re-render regardless of the value that was updated previously and from then on goes for batching. However in your first case the value commited initially was the same as a the value which you pass for update and hence no re-render is triggered

```js
function Counter() {
      const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);
      console.log("in", count)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{count}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => {
            setCount(2) 
          }}>click</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I assume this is one possible reason to this issue. I will check the source code regarding this. Anyway, thank you for your time. :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped